# Grails asset pipeline fails when run from another grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to create part of a web application as a plugin. It's nothing fancy, just a controller or two and a bunch of UI code that uses Angular and Bootstrap. I added the asset pipeline plugin to my plugin and copied over a bunch of common CSS files from another project that's a formal Grails web application (not a plugin like this one). I can verify that the same common files process just fine in that project. When I try to access the CSS files, I get the following error:

```
2014-09-07 14:52:37,013 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - URISyntaxException occurred when processing request:
[GET] /content-creator/assets/css/bootstrap.css
Illegal character in path at index 3: css\/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Illegal character in path at index 3: css\/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    Line | Method
->> 2848 | fail                in java.net.URI$Parser
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   3021 | checkChars          in     ''
|   3105 | parseHierarchical . in     ''
|   3063 | parse               in     ''
|    588 | <init> . . . . . .  in java.net.URI
|     43 | doCall              in asset.pipeline.processors.CssProcessor$_process_closure1
|     36 | process . . . . . . in asset.pipeline.processors.CssProcessor
|     27 | processedStream     in asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile
|    112 | fileContents . . .  in asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor
|     93 | loadContentsForTree in     ''
|     45 | compile . . . . . . in     ''
|     20 | serveAsset          in asset.pipeline.AssetProcessorService
|     28 | index . . . . . . . in asset.pipeline.AssetsController
|     61 | doFilter            in asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineFilter
|   1142 | runWorker . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I was using asset-pipeline 1.9.4. Upgrading to 1.9.9 fixed the issue.